# Issue with plesk installation in Ubuntu - apt packages error

Tags: ubuntu, packages, plesk, apt

OS: Ubuntu 12.04
Plesk 11

Hi all,
I have a problem during installation of plesk when plesk wants to install more packages from apt.

> 385 packages need to be installed.
>    49 packages need to be updated.
>   Sycronizing index file of Debian APT package... 
>   ERROR: An error has
>   occured while PREP actions performing

I translated  the above string from italian. Official error string could be different.

Can someone help me? Plesk does not give any error code. Simply it says that installation process has aborted.

Thank you so much!

Comment: run #export PLESK_INSTALLER_DEBUG=1; ./<ai-binary-name-here> --debug and check /tmp/autoinstaller3.log

Answer (score 0):

Log into your machine using SSH, then run

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and see if this will show you the original error message.

Comment: Thank you!
 Now it says that 0 packages need to be udated and 379 are missing. It ask me if I want to install or go back to preliminar components list. If I agree with installation it returns the same error.
In your opinion should I show all 379 packages and install them manually?

Comment: No, manually installing packages is only a good solution in few cases. I googled a little bit and your original english message is "An error occurred during performing of installation PREP actions". With googling this you will find some more informations, but anyway only 179 matches, so it's not a very common error.

Comment: Wait a minute, i thought you do some installation within plesk and you have set it up already. So, you are trying to do a completely fresh install of plesk? How did you tried to install it (which command)? Have you added the repository of plesk? ``deb http://autoinstall.plesk.com/PSA_11.0.9 squeeze all``

Comment: I should read better. this is the correct line for your sources.list, if not yet added:   
  
``deb http://autoinstall.plesk.com/ubuntu/PSA11 precise all``

Answer (score -1):

Avoid using Ubuntu's own packages with Plesk. You'll potentially break Plesk functionalities. And make sure to run a snapshot before updating the server. :-)

Comment: Could you please explain in more detail - why Ubuntu packages should not be used?